# Confusion regarding javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

While developer a client side application I ran into an error that I believe is related to my incomplete understanding of use of closures. I have trimmed down my code to the following :

```
var fn1 = function(arr){ 
  return function(val){ 
    var idx;
    var x = 20; 
    for (idx in arr) {
      arr[idx]();
    } 
  } 
}

var fn2 = fn1([function(){
  x+= 20; 
  alert(x);
}])
```

Now upon executing : 

`fn2()`

I receive an error :

`ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "x"`

I would like to know why this error is arising and why can't fn2 access the variables defined in the local scope of closure function returned by fn1 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: closures have access to parent scopes in relation to where they were *declared*, not where they are used.

The function returned by `fn1` has access to the scope of its parent function (`fn1` itself), i.e., it has access to `arr`. But the functions inside your array do not have access to variables defined within `fn1` or within the function returned from it, because those functions (inside array) were declared in a different scope.

Regarding the actual problem you're trying to solve with that code, I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. Looks like you're trying to apply some functions to a certain number. I don't understand why that number (`20` in your example) is a constant and not a parameter. Here is my proposed solution for that (no closures!):

```
var applyArrayFunctions = function(arr, x){ 
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        x = arr[i](x);
    }
    return x;
}

var num = 2;
var fnArray = [
    function(val){
      return val + 20; 
    },
    function(val){
      return val * 2; 
    }
];

console.log(applyArrayFunctions(fnArray, num));​ // logs 44​​​
```

Comment: Also explanation needed not to use `fon-in` for arrays and solution to actual question code-wise would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the carification. Very clearly stated. Removed my misconception.

Comment: @Sarfraz I simply removed the hasOwnProperty check for making the code consize. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @Lorefnon: No i mean you should NOT use `for-in` loop for arrays (it is used for objects), use simple `for` loop eg `for (idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {...}`

Comment: I was hoping you could provide a reference (or explain) the problem regarding for-in and arrays  ?

Comment: @Lorefnon: **Simple: Use `for-in` only for objects not arrays.** If you have confusion about the difference between an object and array, you can ask a question to get help on that too.

Comment: @bfavaretto While your solution does indeed resolve the problem, I was simply curious if there did exist a way to inject the value of a variable into the local scope of a priorly unknown function, without passing a parameter.

Comment: @Sarfraz No my confusion was not regarding difference between object and array.For reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays provides a proper discussion on the problems of using for-in with arrays.

Comment: @Lorefnon: Ok nice to know that, have fun.

Comment: @Lorefnon So no, there is not way to inject variables into arbitrary scopes like that. Even closures do not work by injecting anything. One more thing: I think what Sarfraz is trying to say is about `for-in` is (quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)): "iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order" (which is relevant for your example).

Comment: @Sarfraz is right. Unless OP really wants to use an Array as you would an Object, `for-in` is the wrong tool for iteration. Using `.hasOwnProperty()` is not a good fix.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the error is in the line `x+=20`

`var x = 20` only exists inside the scope of the anonymous function returned by `fn1`.
`x+=20` evaluates before `fn1` does, so `x` doesn't even exist at that time.